# SyntaxError using Wijmo with RequireJs / Typescript

Tags: typescript, requirejs, amd, wijmo, wijmo5

I have a project set up, that uses `Typescript` and `RequireJS` to load the dependencies. I fail to get the `wijmo.grid` dependecy to work.

I started with the [Quickstart manual from Grapecity](https://www.grapecity.com/wijmo/docs/GettingStarted/QuickStart/QuickStart-PureJS) and adjusted it into my combination of Typescript & RequireJs.

This is what I want to do in `test.ts`:

```
import { FlexGrid} from '@grapecity/wijmo.grid';

export class TestViewModel {
    constructor() {
        let grid = new FlexGrid('#hostElement');
    }
}
```

The script tags:

```
<script src="~/lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/require-config.js"></script>
<script>
    require(
        ["my-test"],
        function (myTest) {
            var viewModel = new myTest.TestViewModel();
        }
    );
</script>
```

This is my `require-config.ts`:

```
declare var require: any;
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/",
    paths: {
        "jquery": [
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery",
            "lib/jquery/dist/jquery-3.4.1"
        ],
        "knockout": [
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-debug",
            "lib/knockout/knockout-3.5.0.debug"
        ],
        "@grapecity/wijmo.grid": [
            "lib/@grapecity/wijmo.grid/es5-esm"
        ],
        "my-test": "js/test"
    },
    waitSeconds: 15
});
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/js/",
    "module": "amd",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Now when I access that page, I expect it to work, but I get an error:

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module (es5-esm.js:14:365)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:**

I also tried using the index-module in `require-config.ts`:

```
"@grapecity/wijmo.grid": [
    "lib/@grapecity/wijmo.grid/index"
],
```

This leads to a different error:

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined (index.js:14:379)
```

It seems like the wijmo modules are build targeting other module loaders than stated, or I am still missing some configuration.

Comment: That means that `lib/@grapecity/wijmo.grid/es5-esm` is not in the right format, as is to be expected give the file name. Point your dependency to a different output or transpile the code using TypeScript or something

Comment: @AluanHaddad  That filename version suggests it is  for es5, so I am confused why it would be wrong. About esm I read it's for compatibility with es5, so that seems right to me too. Also the other versions are all newer, I think for es2015.

Comment: es5-esm msans everything is transpiled to es5 except module constructs (`import`, `export`).

Comment: https://www.grapecity.com/wijmo/docs/GettingStarted/NPM-Module-Formats

Answer (score 0):

That means that lib/@grapecity/wijmo.grid/es5-esm is not in the right format, as is to be expected give the file name. You can either map your dependency to a different output or transpile the code using TypeScript or Babel or something.

In particular, the filename `es5-esm.js` suggests that everything is transpiled to es5 except module constructs (`import`, `export`).

If we consult the [documentation](https://www.grapecity.com/wijmo/docs/GettingStarted/Npm-Module-Formats), we see that this is in fact the case.

> Wijmo npm packages provide their content in multiple formats, which
>   are combinations of the language version (ES5 or ES2015) and module
>   format (CommonJS or ESM). Every format in the installed package folder
>   is represented by a separate .js file, referenced by a special field
>   in the package.json file. Modern bundlers like Webpack can use a
>   package file in the preferred format, depending on the bundler
>   configuration. Bundlers without this capability will use the main
>   field in package.json to resolve module name to a specific .js file.
>   In the Wijmo packages, it is the index.js file which contains the
>   (most compatible) ES5 + CommonJS format.

Therefore,

```
 paths: {
   "@grapecity/wijmo.grid": [
     "lib/@grapecity/wijmo.grid/index"
    ],
 }
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I tried using             "lib/@grapecity/wijmo.grid/main", but it wont load with it.
"Error: Script error for "@grapecity/wijmo.grid", needed by: my-test".
I think that part in the docs is refering to package.json, which has this entry: "main": "./index.js",

Comment: Using "lib/@grapecity/wijmo.grid/index" gives the me another error: "ReferenceError: exports is not defined". It seems like none of them is in the right format. I guess I will have to include transpiling the wijmo*.ts files in my project. I don't think I should be required to do so, just bc im targeting ES5 with AMD.

Comment: RequireJS needs should figure out that it's cjs... Hmmm.